# add blank space before image

Tags: spacing, graphics

I'm drawing two images, one on top and one in the bottom, and I want them to be aligned. One of them has some extra blank space one its left side, so I need to realign it manually:

```
\begin{minipage}{9em}
    \includegraphics[height=3em]{images/img1.png} \\
    \includegraphics[height=3em]{images/img2.png} 
\end{minipage}
```

I tried to add `\hspace{some_number}` to either one of them to see the effect, but nothing happened. What should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  The images appear aligned to me, so without a MWE, not sure how to determine the source of the problem.  You could try `\hspace*{}` but you should _not_ need to resort to a  manual tweak like that to align things.

Comment: They are aligned, but as I said above one image has some extra blank space in it on its left side, so I have to move it a little bit to the left or I have to move the other one a little bit to the right.

Comment: The space is /inside/ the image, it's not introduced by latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includegraphics` of package `graphicx` knows option `trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>`. Default unit is `bp`:

```
\includegraphics[trim=10 0 0 1mm]{img.png}% trims 10bp from the left and 1mm from the top
```

Or crop the image with image editing software.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\hspace*{-<length>}` to move one of the images to the left (or a postive amount to move to the right) to compensate for the extra space in the image itself:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove demo option for real use.

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{9em}
    \includegraphics[height=3em]{images/img1.png} \\
    \hspace*{-1ex}\includegraphics[height=3em]{images/img2.png} 
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would work but isn't the recommended approach, right? I'm sure it's not good practice to try and put images and then align them using such code. Probably something with `subfig` etc would be better?

Comment: @recluze: Yep Heiko's answer is the correct approach for this specific problem. I was addressing the question asked.